# Enlightenment 22 -- Binding cursor movement to keys

Tags: enlightenment, void-linux

I've seen that it's possible for X11-based desktops to move the cursor/pointer around using keys with stuff like [xdotool](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) or [keynav](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/keynav/).

While these look quite convenient, I've been trying to do the same using non-X11 methods. Here's what I've tried in e22:

- No action relating to mouse movement in the Key Bindings section of the settings panel.
- No way to bind mouse movement to keypad (or any other keys for that matter) in the Mouse section of the settings panel just like Gnome users could do.
- and I haven't found the mouse structs in the few e_bindings files that I've inspected.

Is it possible to move the cursor using only e configuration?

If not, what possibilities do I have that don't involve X11?

Void Linux, 4.19.28
Enlightenment 0.22.4